# Dynamic Pivot Needed with Row_Number()

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, row-number, dynamic-columns

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

I have data that looks like this:

```
Client ID        Value
-------------------------------
12345            Did Not Meet
12345            Did Not Meet
12345            Partially Met
12346            Partially Met
12346            Partially Met
12346            Partially Met
12347            Partially Met
12347            Partially Met
12347            Did Not Meet
12347            Met
```

and I'd like the results to appear like this:

```
Client ID                Value1                Value2                   Value3                      Value4

12345                    Did Not Meet           Did Not Meet            Partially Met                NULL
12346                    Partially Met          Partially Met           Partially Met                NULL
12347                    Partially Met          Partially Met           Did Not Meet                 Met
```

The columns are unknown so I know I need a dynamic query. I have tried a dynamic query with a pivot function but only got groupings under the same type of value. So the aggregate function worked against me.

This was the query I tried:

```
Declare @Columns nvarchar(max); 
Declare @DynamicPivotQuery nvarchar(max);   

Select @Columns=    
COALESCE(@Columns+',','')+QUOTENAME(Value)  
from (select distinct Document.Value
from Document d 
join Client c on d.clientid=c.id    
    )
 as t1  


Set @DynamicPivotQuery= 
 N'Select ClientID, ' + @Columns + '    
 from   
 (select Document.ClientID, 
  DocumentFact.Value,   
   from Document d
   join Client c on d.clientid=c.id 
 ) p    
Pivot (max(Value) for Value in ('+@Columns+'))  
 as pivottable  
 order by ClientID;'
```

Exec (@DynamicPivotQuery)

Next I added the row_number and partition functions but can't seem to debug this. The error I get is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Which is near the XML Path function.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
select @Columns=    
COALESCE(@Columns+',','')+QUOTENAME(Value)  
from (select distinct Document.Value    
, 'name'+ CAST (row_number() over   
(Partition BY clientid order by clientid) as NVARCHAR (10)) as Cols 
from document d
join Clients c on d.clientid=c.id   

 t1 

 --FOR XML PATH('')),      1, 1, N'');
 FOR XML PATH('')), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')    
  order by ClientID
```

Comment: Can you not do it in a script, like php, python, javascript?

Comment: @WixLove please feel free to give a feedback on [below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29570036/3208640)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with using a `cte`, with `row_number` you can achieve the result:

*Your Schema:*

```
create table your_table([Client ID] int ,Value varchar(50));
insert into your_table values
(12345,            'Did Not Meet'),
(12345,            'Did Not Meet'),
(12345,            'Partially Met'),
(12346,            'Partially Met'),
(12346,            'Partially Met'),
(12346,            'Partially Met'),
(12347,            'Partially Met'),
(12347,            'Partially Met'),
(12347,            'Did Not Meet'),
(12347,            'Met');
```

*The query:*

```
with cte as
(
 select [Client ID] ci,value,
        row_number() over(partition by [Client ID] order by value) as rn
 from your_table
)
select distinct ci as [Client ID],
       (select ct.value from cte ct where ct.ci=cte.ci and ct.rn=1) value1,
       (select ct.value from cte ct where ct.ci=cte.ci and ct.rn=2) value2,
       (select ct.value from cte ct where ct.ci=cte.ci and ct.rn=3) value3,
       (select ct.value from cte ct where ct.ci=cte.ci and ct.rn=4) value4
from cte
```

*The Result:*

```
Client ID   value1          value2          value3          value4
12345       Did Not Meet    Did Not Meet    Partially Met   (null)
12346       Partially Met   Partially Met   Partially Met   (null)
12347       Did Not Meet    Met Partially   Met Partially    Met
```

Comment: Sorry--am rewriting my comment because it wasn't clear the first time. Thank you for the response. I have tried to run your example on SQL Fiddle can't get your query to run at all. The post above was a simplified version of my query. I have customized my more complicated query and don't get an error message but the query runs over 15 minutes. I don't know why I can't get your query to run in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I was finally able to make your suggested query work by adding some filters which made the run time much faster so I could see the results. It's exactly what I wanted and I thank you much!

Comment: You are welcome bro, just in `select` part after the `cte` you can also use 4 `self joins` instead of the subqueries.