# BigQuery - Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I'm trying to pivot a table from

| ID | DATE | DATA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2022-05-01 | "Stringvalue.. rank:1" |
| 12345 | 2022-05-01 | "Stringvalue.. rank:2" |
| 67890 | 2022-05-01 | "Stringvalue.. rank:2" |
| 67890 | 2022-05-01 | "Stringvalue.. rank:2" |

~

| ID | DATE | DATA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2022-05-01 | "Stringvalue.. rank:23" |
| 12345 | 2022-05-01 | "Stringvalue.. rank:24" |
| 67890 | 2022-05-01 | "Stringvalue.. rank:23" |
| 67890 | 2022-05-01 | "Stringvalue.. rank:24" |

to

| ID | DATE | rank 1 | rank 2 | ... | rank 24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2022-05-01 | "Stringvalue.. rank:1" | "Stringvalue.. rank:2" |  | "Stringvalue.. rank:23" |
| 67890 | 2022-05-01 | "Stringvalue.. rank:1" | "Stringvalue.. rank:2" |  | "Stringvalue.. rank:24" |

referring to this: [Dynamic Pivot Needed with Row_Number()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569801/dynamic-pivot-needed-with-row-number), I tried implementing this by

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Date,
  (select ct.Data from cte ct where ct.ID= cte.ID and ct.Date = cte.Date and ct.rank =1) AS Ghour_1,
  (select ct.Data from cte ct where ct.ID = cte.ID and ct.Date= cte.Date and ct.rank =2) AS Ghour_2,
.
.
.

ct.Date = cte.Date and ct.rank =23) AS Ghour_23,
  (select ct.Data from cte ct where ct.ID = cte.ID and ct.Date = cte.Date and ct.rank =24) AS Ghour_24,
   from cte
```

but it is throwing resources exceeded error, is this because I have too many subquery select statements? Could anyone please suggest how to optimise this query?

Comment: Have many distinct values `DATA` field have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below as a starting point

```
select * from (
  select *, replace(regexp_extract(data, r'\brank:(\d+)$'), ':', '') rank
  from your_table
)
pivot (any_value(data) as rank for rank in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Above is easy to transform to dynamic pivot  - see multiple examples here on SO - in particular at least few of my answers dedicated to this

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! Yes will look into other example of dynamic pivot